# How to run all tests in solution

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, mstest

It appears that I can run all my tests in the solution in one go from the command line using MSTest if I use the /testmetadata flag as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182487.aspx

I'm running SQL Server DB Unit tests in Visual Studio 2013, wherein I don't seem to have a vsmdi file at all, and I'm unable to find a way to add one either. I tried creating a testsettings file, but it doesn't discover any tests (shows "No tests to run") when I invoke MSTest.

Is there a way I can have MSTest run all my tests in a VS2013 solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I wanted to close this open question. My intention was to run all tests in one go from out Hudson CI server, so I wrote a basic console app to find and invoke MSTest on all DLL files inside the solution folder. This app is executed after the project is built in release mode.

```
string execId = null;
string className = null;
string testName = null;
string testResult = null;
string resultLine = null;
List<string> results = new List<string>();
XmlDocument resultsDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode executionNode = null;
XmlNode testMethodNode = null;

// Define the test instance settings
Process testInstance = null;
ProcessStartInfo testInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
};

// Fetch project list from the disk
List<string> excluded = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExcludedProjects"].Split(',').ToList();
DirectoryInfo assemblyPath = new DirectoryInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
DirectoryInfo[] directories = assemblyPath.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.GetDirectories();

// Create a test worklist
List<string> worklist = directories.Where(t => !excluded.Contains(t.Name))
                                    .Select(t => String.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MSTestCommand"], t.FullName, t.Name))
                                    .ToList();

// Start test execution
Console.WriteLine("Starting Execution...");
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("Results               Top Level Tests");
Console.WriteLine("-------               ---------------");

// Remove any existing run results
if (File.Exists("UnitTests.trx"))
{
    File.Delete("UnitTests.trx");
}

// Run each project in the worklist
foreach (string item in worklist)
{
    testInfo.FileName = item;
    testInstance = Process.Start(testInfo);
    testInstance.WaitForExit();

    if (File.Exists("UnitTests.trx"))
    {
        resultsDoc = new XmlDocument();
        resultsDoc.Load("UnitTests.trx");

        foreach (XmlNode result in resultsDoc.GetElementsByTagName("UnitTestResult"))
        {
            // Get the execution ID for the test
            execId = result.Attributes["executionId"].Value;

            // Find the execution and test method nodes
            executionNode = resultsDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Execution")
                                        .OfType<XmlNode>()
                                        .Where(n => n.Attributes["id"] != null && n.Attributes["id"].Value.Equals(execId))
                                        .First();

            testMethodNode = executionNode.ParentNode
                                            .ChildNodes
                                            .OfType<XmlNode>()
                                            .Where(n => n.Name.Equals("TestMethod"))
                                            .First();

            // Get the class name, test name and result
            className = testMethodNode.Attributes["className"].Value.Split(',')[0];
            testName = result.Attributes["testName"].Value;
            testResult = result.Attributes["outcome"].Value;
            resultLine = String.Format("{0}                {1}.{2}", testResult, className, testName);

            results.Add(resultLine);
            Console.WriteLine(resultLine);
        }

        File.Delete("UnitTests.trx");
    }
}

// Calculate passed / failed test case count
int passed = results.Where(r => r.StartsWith("Passed")).Count();
int failed = results.Where(r => r.StartsWith("Failed")).Count();

// Print the summary
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Summary");
Console.WriteLine("-------");
Console.WriteLine("Test Run {0}", failed > 0 ? "Failed." : "Passed.");
Console.WriteLine();

if (passed > 0)
    Console.WriteLine("\tPassed {0,7}", passed);

if (failed > 0)
    Console.WriteLine("\tFailed {0,7}", failed);

Console.WriteLine("\t--------------");
Console.WriteLine("\tTotal {0,8}", results.Count);

if (failed > 0)
    Environment.Exit(-1);
else
    Environment.Exit(0);
```

My App.config file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ExcludedProjects" value="UnitTests.Bootstrap,UnitTests.Utils" />
    <add key="MSTestCommand" value="&quot;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe&quot; /testcontainer:&quot;{0}\bin\Release\{1}.dll&quot; /nologo /resultsfile:&quot;UnitTests.trx&quot;" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 5):

MsTest is kind of the "deprecated" test framework of Visual Studio 2013. it's still used for some types of tests, but many of the other tests that can be executed now live in the new Agile Test Runner. Now SQL Database Unit Tests seems to still be in the category of "Some types" and need to be executed through MsTest.exe.

The easiest way is to use the [`/TestContainer` commandline switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182487.aspx) and use a naming pattern for your test projects. That way you can quickly grab all the assemblies with a specific naming pattern and then feed them to MsTest. Simple powershell command could be used to grab all the files that adhere to your pattern and then feed them to the commandline.

The vsmdi will still work in Visual Studio 2013, but the editor has been removed from the tool, plus there is no template for it anymore. So it's very hard to use. This is what Microsoft has to say about the VSDMI's:

> **Caution**
> Test lists are no longer fully supported in Visual Studio 2012:
>
> - You cannot create new test lists.
> - You cannot run test list tests from within Visual Studio.
> - If you upgraded from Visual Studio 2010, and had test list in your solution, you can continue to edit it in Visual Studio.
> - You can continue to run test list using mstest.exe from the command line, as described above.
> - If you were using a test list in your build definition, you can continue to use it.

Basically they're telling you to stop using this technique and use a combination of `TestCategory`'s to create easy to execute tests groups.

As you can add multiple parameters for test containers, you can all group them into one call:

```
/testcontainer:[file name]        Load a file that contains tests. You can
                                  Specify this option more than once to
                                  load multiple test files.
                                  Examples:
                                    /testcontainer:mytestproject.dll
                                    /testcontainer:loadtest1.loadtest

MsTest /testcontainer:assemblyone.dll /testcontainer:assemblytwo.dll /testcontainer:assembly3.dll
```

To run MsTest on multiple assemblies at once. And do not (yet) make use of XUnit .NET or NUnit, as these cannot be combined into one report without switching to the new Agile test runner.

Comment: Yes. But i need 1 report.

Comment: For those giving -1's, can you comment on the reason so I have a chance to improve the answer?

Comment: I fear they just fight for the bounty. I saw this behavior before.

Comment: If you have any thoughts, please add them. I'm not in it for the bounty. I have respect enough as is :). If the `/testcontainer` option doesn't work for you, then please explain why it does not work. There are limitations of course. Worst case you'll need to combine the different output xmls into one.

Comment: "Agile Test Runner" seems to be a TFS only thing? I need to be using TFS and not something like jenkins in order to use it?

Comment: @red888 the Agile test Runner is actually the `vstest.console.exe` that ships with recent versions of Visual Studio. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx . In the TFS XAML build editor this is identified by "Agile test runner". You can call vstest.console.exe directly from jenkins if you wanted to.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will help you or not, but I use [Invoke-MsBuild](https://invokemsbuild.codeplex.com/). Its a PowerShell module that should does exactly what you need. I don't know if you were looking for a PowerShell solution or not, but it works great!

It also has a sister script, [Invoke-MsTest](https://invokemstest.codeplex.com/) for running MsTest instead of MsBuild.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, I often want to run tests as console application, simply because I find it much easier to debug this for some reason... Over the years I've created a few small test helpers to help me out; I suppose you can use them with your CI solution quite easily.

I understand this isn't your question entirely; however, since you're looking for a CI solution and mention visual studio, this should solve it quite nicely.

Just to let you know, my little framework is a bit bigger than this, but the things that are missing are quite easy to add. Basically what I left out is everything for logging and the fact that I test different assemblies in different app domains (because of possible DLL conflicts and state). More on that below.

One thing to notice is that I do not catch any exceptions in the process below. My main focus is making it easy to debug your application when troubleshooting. I have a separate (but similar) implementation for CI that basically adds try/catches on the comment points below.

There's only one catch to this method: Visual Studio won't copy all the assemblies you reference; it'll only copy assemblies that you use in the code. A simple workaround for this is to introduce a method (which is never called) which uses one type in the DLL you're testing. That way, your assembly will be copied and everything will work nicely.

Here's the code:

```
static class TestHelpers
{
    public static void TestAll(this object o)
    {
        foreach (MethodInfo meth in o.GetType().GetMethods().
            Where((a) => a.GetCustomAttributes(true).
                Any((b) => b.GetType().Name.Contains("TestMethod"))))
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("--- Testing {0} ---", meth.Name);
            Console.WriteLine();

            // Add exception handling here for your CI solution.
            var del = (Action)meth.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), o);
            del();

            // NOTE: Don't use meth.Invoke(o, new object[0]); ! It'll eat your exception!

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    public static void TestAll(this Assembly ass)
    {
        HashSet<AssemblyName> visited = new HashSet<AssemblyName>();
        Stack<Assembly> todo = new Stack<Assembly>();
        todo.Push(ass);

        HandleStack(visited, todo);

    }

    private static void HandleStack(HashSet<AssemblyName> visited, Stack<Assembly> todo)
    {
        while (todo.Count > 0)
        {
            var assembly = todo.Pop();

            // Collect all assemblies that are related
            foreach (var refass in assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies())
            {
                TryAdd(refass, visited, todo);
            }

            foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes().
                Where((a) => a.GetCustomAttributes(true).
                    Any((b) => b.GetType().Name.Contains("TestClass"))))
            {
                // Add exception handling here for your CI solution.
                var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                obj.TestAll();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void TestAll()
    {
        HashSet<AssemblyName> visited = new HashSet<AssemblyName>();
        Stack<Assembly> todo = new Stack<Assembly>();

        foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            TryAdd(assembly.GetName(), visited, todo);
        }

        HandleStack(visited, todo);
    }

    private static void TryAdd(AssemblyName ass, HashSet<AssemblyName> visited, Stack<Assembly> todo)
    {
        try
        {
            var reference = Assembly.Load(ass);

            if (reference != null &&
                !reference.GlobalAssemblyCache &&           // Ignore GAC
                reference.FullName != null && 
                !reference.FullName.StartsWith("ms") &&     // mscorlib and other microsoft stuff
                !reference.FullName.StartsWith("vshost") && // visual studio host process
                !reference.FullName.StartsWith("System"))   // System libraries
            {
                if (visited.Add(reference.GetName()))       // We don't want to test assemblies twice
                {
                    todo.Push(reference);                   // Queue assembly for processing
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // Perhaps log something here... I currently don't because I don't care...
        }
    }
}
```

How to use this code:

1. You can simply call `TestHelpers.TestAll()` to test all assemblies, referenced assemblies, indirectly referenced assemblies, etc. This is probably what you want to do in CI.
2. You can call `TestHelpers.TestAll(assembly)` to test a single assembly with all referenced assemblies. This can be useful when you're splitting tests across multiple assemblies and/or when your debugging.
3. You can call `new MyObject().TestAll()` to invoke all tests in a single object. This is particularly helpful when debugging.

If you're using appdomains like me, you should make a single appdomain for a DLL you load dynamically from a folder and use TestAll on that. Also, if you use a scratch folder, you might want to empty that between tests. That way, multiple test framework versions and multiple tests won't interact with each other. Particularly if your tests use state (e.g. static variables), this might be a good practice. There are tons of examples for `CreateInstanceAndUnwrap` online that will help you out with this.

One thing to note is that I use a delegate instead of the `method.Invoke`. This basically means your exception object won't be eaten by Reflection, which means your debugger won't be broken. Also note that I check attributes by name, which means this will work with different frameworks - as long as the attribute names match.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Read the Caution part in your own link. It's no longer supported in VST 2012 the way you do it.

Maybe this update version can help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182490.aspx